# Building ATLAS (and later Octave w/ ATLAS)

Tags: 14.04, make, configure, octave

I'm trying to set up ATLAS (so I can later compile octave with ATLAS support).

If I'm correct, I still need to build this manually due to the environment specific optimizations. I do see a package for ATLAS, but it looks like it's using the cross platform generic build options (e.g. "it'll be slow").

So, running the configure script as described in the [docs](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node6.html) seems to go poorly. As a java developer I never do well at making heads or tails of errors in these build processes. Am I missing dependencies (if so is there any documentation on what I need)?

```
allusers@vbubuntu:~/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu$ ../configure -b 64 -D c -DPentiumCPS=3000 --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/home/allusers/Downloads/lapack-3.5.0.tgz

make: `xconfig' is up to date.
./xconfig -d s /home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu/../ -d b /home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu  -b 64 -D c -DPentiumCPS=3000 -Si lapackref 1

OS configured as Linux (1)

Assembly configured as GAS_x8664 (2)

Vector ISA Extension configured as  SSE3 (6,448)
ERROR: enum fam=3, chip=2, mach=0
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 44
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_x86] Error 2

Architecture configured as  Corei1 (25)
ERROR: enum fam=3, chip=2, mach=0
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 44
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_x86] Error 2

Clock rate configured as 2350Mhz
ERROR: enum fam=3, chip=2, mach=0
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 44
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_x86] Error 2

Maximum number of threads configured as  4
Parallel make command configured as '$(MAKE) -j 4'
ERROR: enum fam=3, chip=2, mach=0
make[3]: *** [atlas_run] Error 44
make[2]: *** [IRunArchInfo_x86] Error 2
Cannot detect CPU throttling.
rm -f config1.out
make atlas_run atldir=/home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu exe=xprobe_comp redir=config1.out \
                args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 25 -Si nof77 0 -V 448   -b 64 -d b /home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu'
cd /home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu ; ./xprobe_comp -v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 25 -Si nof77 0 -V 448   -b 64 -d b /home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu > config1.out
make[2]: gfortran: Command not found
make[2]: *** [IRunF77Comp] Error 127
make[2]: g77: Command not found
make[2]: *** [IRunF77Comp] Error 127
make[2]: f77: Command not found
make[2]: *** [IRunF77Comp] Error 127


Unable to find usable compiler for F77; abortingMake sure compilers are in your path, and specify good compilers to configure
(see INSTALL.txt or 'configure --help' for details)make[1]: *** [atlas_run] Error 8
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu'
make: *** [IRun_comp] Error 2
ERROR 512 IN SYSCMND: 'make IRun_comp args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 25 -Si nof77 0 -V 448   -b 64"'
mkdir src bin tune interfaces
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘src’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘bin’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘tune’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘interfaces’: File exists
make: *** [make_subdirs] Error 1
make -f Make.top startup
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu'
Make.top:1: Make.inc: No such file or directory
Make.top:325: warning: overriding commands for target `/AtlasTest'
Make.top:76: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/AtlasTest'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Make.inc'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/allusers/Downloads/atlas3.10.1/build_vbubuntu'
make: *** [startup] Error 2
mv: cannot move ‘lapack-3.5.0’ to ‘../reference/lapack-3.5.0’: Directory not empty
mv: cannot stat ‘lib/Makefile’: No such file or directory
../configure: 450: ../configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
../configure: 451: ../configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
../configure: 452: ../configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
../configure: 453: ../configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
../configure: 509: ../configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
DONE configure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like these were the dependencies it needed, the build process is now running. These things are never just easily documented in a nice consumable form.

For Ubuntu (gfortran, g77, and f77 respectively):

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran f2c libcnf-dev
```

Also, anyone finding this question may find this related stackoverflow question of use:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876286/building-octave-from-source-did-atlas-get-included-properly-in-octaves-confi

Answer (score 12):

The best way to build the ATLAS library customized to your particular processor is to follow the instructions in `/usr/share/doc/libatlas3-base/README.Debian` (also available for reading online [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/atlas/trusty/view/head:/debian/README.Debian)). The instructions tell explicitly how to rebuild the `atlas` source package for Debian/Ubuntu in a way that will give you custom-built packages that can be installed in place of packages provided in the official repositories.

The relevant excerpt from `README.Debian` says:

> ### Building Optimized Atlas Packages on your ARCH
>
> Building your own optimized packages of Atlas is straightforward.
>   Just get the sources of the package and its build-dependencies:
>
> ```
> # apt-get source atlas
> # apt-get build-dep atlas
> # apt-get install devscripts
> ```
>
> and type the following from the atlas source subdir:
>
> ```
> # fakeroot debian/rules custom
> ```
>
> it should produce a package called:
>
> `../libatlas3-base_*.deb`
>
> which is optimized for the architecture Atlas has been built on. Then install
>   the package using `dpkg -i`.

Comment: After the last 'dpkg -i' step, how do I compile/link against ATLAS' CBLAS and CLAPACK? I don't have any ATLAS in /usr/local. What -I and -L argumets should I pass to g++? I tried 'g++ main.cpp -I$~/atlas-xxxx/include -L~/atlas-xxxx/build/atlas-base/lib/ -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas', but it gives me '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas'. Thanks.

Comment: @Salmonstrikes Install the `libatlas-base-dev` and `libatlas-dev` packages that were also built, and the libraries are installed for building in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked For future reference, to get code to compile, I needed: 1) to use extern "C" guards for both 'cblas.h' and 'clapack.h' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786237/atlas-gemm-linking-undefined-reference-to-cblas-sgemm 2) 'g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include/atlas -lf77blas -lcblas -llapack_atlas'; for some reason '-llapack' alone doesn't work and I needed '-llapack_atlas'